# How to transfer data from model to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a basic todo app.

I created a new view called view_list which basically shows the list I press "show" in my lists archives.

I have this function in my model

```
public function get_list_details() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lists";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row();
}
```

My controller is

```
public function show_list() {
    $this->load->model('model_lists');
    $data = $this->model_lists->get_list_details();
    $this->load->view('lists/view_list', $data);
}
```

How do I pass the id of the list I clicked on?

Currently the view list opens in tab using the list unique id 
view_list?lid=e4zVyKBHXu

Comment: How did you go? I posted my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it like

```
public function show_list() {
    $this->load->model('model_lists');
    $model_data = $this->model_lists->get_list_details();
    $data['somename'] = $model_data->column_name;

    $this->load->view('lists/view_list', $data);
}
```

On view

```
<?php echo $somename;?>
```

Here are a good examples http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Get all list

```
public function get_list_details() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lists";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller function

```
public function show_list() {
    $this->load->model('model_lists');
    $data['results'] = $this->model_lists->get_list_details();

    $this->load->view('lists/view_list', $data);
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result) {?>
  <?php echo $result->column_name;?>
<?php }?>
```